# ASP.Net: How to control div-style in backend?

Tags: asp.net

I will control the style from a div-container from the backend (c#, code behind).

I will not use the runat="server"-tag, because the div-id is much used in javaScript.

How to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have a div that you want to use in code behind and in jQuery.

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server"></div>
```

As we both know, when you view the source code of the page the id is changed by asp.net. So to access it using jQuery do this:

```
$("#<%=myDiv.ClientID %>")
```

Comment: Should add a note that this won't work if JavaScript is external (which it is in 90% of the cases). Which is why i suggested literal.

Comment: document.getElementById( ' $("#<%=MiddleReg.ClientID %>") ' ).setAttribute( 'style', 'display:none' );  - Won't work

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution at all. Why would you want to bind your javascript code to your server code that tight. They should be as separated as possible, preferably the scripts should be defined in a separate file that you include.

Comment: Agreed. Use a literal or script registration to register the client ID to javascript on the page, so **any** script that is included on the page (internal *or* external) can make use of it. And BTW remove the `#` from the code soup - this is for databinding.

Comment: @Kovu, why are you using document.getElementById and then using jQuery inside of it.

Answer (score 3):

I would do as RPM1984 suggest and use `ClientIdMode="Static"` if you use .Net 4.0 as he says. But if that is not an option just wrap your div in a div that hasn't `runat="server"` like:

```
<div id="wrapperDiv">
    <div id="innerDiv" runat="server">additional stuff</div>
</div>
```

That should work and it would be fairly straight forward to access the inner div using the outer div's id in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wrapperDiv > div').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: I think it is a little verbose in the sense you shouldn't have to do it like that, but what to do when working with legacy asp.net webforms applications :)...

Answer (score 0):

You **have to** make it runat=server if you want to access it from the code behind - simple as that.

If it's "much used" in JavaScript - set the ClientId in a literal control, and access it that way from JavaScript.

Or if your on .NET 4, set the ClientIdMode="Static".

**EDIT**

Here's how you can use a literal control to hold onto the client id (so you can use it in JavaScript):

ASPX:

```
<asp:Literal id="DivClientId" runat="server"/>
```

ASPX.CS:

```
DivClentId.Text = string.Format("<script type=\"text/javascript\">var divId = {0};</script>", ServerSideDiv.ClientId);
```

JavaScript:

```
var div = document.getElementById(divId);
```

Comment: I don't understand, what is the ClientID in a literal control?

Answer (score 0):

In .net 4.0 just use a panel control (which gets rendered as a div) and set the ClientIDMode to static. So you can set your styles on the server-side and still easily access it in your JS code.